# Designing an email "api"

Tags: google-app-engine, email, incoming-mail

So, im building this webservice on Googles app engine, and i would like it to receive emails.

The thing is, i need to authorize the incoming mails and determine a destination based on *alone* on the **TO** field. This is to let people integrate the service in whatever email sending systems they already have running.

At least i need to variables, a key and a destination (which is also an email address):

An example could be:

`af922514-60bc-4595-956d-ec29e6351d8e,kristian@mide.dk@application.appspotmail.com`

Thats not really going to work (i think), is there any way to escape the first @, or should i go a completely other way around this?

I've thought about base encoding it so:

```
af922514-60bc-4595-956d-ec29e6351d8e,kristian@mide.dk@application.appspotmail.com
```

besomes this:

```
YWY5MjI1MTQtNjBiYy00NTk1LTk1NmQtZWMyOWU2MzUxZDhlLGtyaXN0aWFuQG1pZGUuZGs=@application.appspotmail.com
```

I'm not sure the ending '=' is allowed in email addresses though

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Just about anything is permissible in the user part of an email address, with correct escaping. But that doesn't mean it's a good idea - you're likely to encounter many email systems that are not RFC compliant when it comes to 'weird' email addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all a comma would be no-go, since it would suggest multiple recipients, most mail clients will see the comma as a separator.

What you could do is format it like this:

> some-var+recipient-addresse+domain.tld@someapp.appspotmail.com

When your app receives the email, you simply do a regexp that matches everything until the first + sign. There you have your variable, then match the rest until a @ sign, replace the last + with a @ and you have the email.

This would also allow the recipient email to contain + since you're only replacing the first and last + sign.

Answer (score 0):

Since `+` doesn't belong in a hostname, you could replace the last `+` with `@` so that:

`some-id,myinbox+tag+gmail.com@someapp.appspotmail.com`

translates to:

`myinbox+tag@gmail.com` with `some-id`